# HMAC SHA256 base64 encoded

Tags: lua, base64, sha256, hmac

There is a Node.JS code which creates a signature for Azure.

```
var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");
```

How can I create the same signature using LUA. (I think I need to use Lua-Lockbox for this)

https://github.com/somesocks/lua-lockbox

I can see it has Hmac, sha256 and base64 primitives but I'm not sure how I can implement this code as LUA

Is there any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know lua-lockbox, but it looks like this should work:

```
local stream = require "lockbox.util.stream"
local hmac = require "lockbox.mac.hmac"
local sha256 = require "lockbox.digest.sha2_256"
local base64 = require "lockbox.util.base64"

local body = stream.fromString("thisisthebody")
local key = {("thekey"):byte(1,-1)}

local digest = hmac()
    .setBlockSize(64)
    .setDigest(sha256)
    .setKey(key)
    .init()
    .update(body)
    .finish()
    .asBytes()

local base64_digest = base64.fromArray(digest)

print(base64_digest)
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I will try and let you know the result.

Comment: in my javascript code key is calculating like var key = new Buffer("ABC", "base64"); what does mean new Buffer?? How can I do the same thing in LUA? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it means your key "ABC" is encoded as Base64. In Lua you can do this I think: `local key = base64.toArray("ABC")`.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. I'm trying to create below key. there are nodejs and .net codes but I cannot create same value using lua. When you have time, if you look at it, you can save my life :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN